# Add a field which is a mapping from another in $addFields mongo aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a Mongo collection of values against metrics, for example:

```
[
    {"metric": "A", "value": 1.0},
    {"metric": "B", "value": 0.5}
]
```

I want to write an aggregate query which will do a weighted average of these, but the weight of each metric isn't in the collection - it's dynamically set at the point the query is written.

So I need to add a `weight` field, mapping from the metric field to some double. I've tried this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            metricWeight: {"A": 2.0, "B": 5.0}["$metric"]
        }
    }
])
```

ie. trying to define the map in-line as a JS object and then index it with the `metric` field - but this gives me `undefined` as every `metricWeight`.

Expected output of this stage of the pipeline would be:

```
[
    {"metric": "A", "value": 1.0, "metricWeight": 2.0},
    {"metric": "B", "value": 0.5, "metricWeight": 5.0}
]
```

Is there any way to achieve this using a Mongo aggregate query?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Added to question above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
const object = { "A": 2.0, "B": 5.0 }

db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "keys": {
      "$objectToArray": object
    }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "metric": 1,
    "value": 1,
    "metricWeight": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        "$keys.v",
        { "$indexOfArray": ["$keys.k", "$metric"] }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```